# dynamic typecasting of managed object properties when doing setValuesForKeysWithDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a few NSManagedObject classes. I am pulling down some JSON data from a server which I parse into an NSDictionary object. When the conversion from JSON to NSDictionary occurs, all of my data is cast as NSStrings. When I then map this dictionary to my managedObject I get this:

```
Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "idexpert"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = __NSCFString; value = 1.'
```

So my managedobject is looking for an NSNumber but it's getting a string and throwing an exception

Is there a way that when I call `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` I can automagically cast the values properly for the managedobject they are going into?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the json you are receiving actually has number values and they are getting cast as string you should get a new json parser.  I recommend NXJson.  Otherwise there wont be any magical casting happening.

If the json is returning strings such as {"idexpert":"1"} then you can override setValuesForKeysWithDictionary and do something like the code below;

```
-(void)setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)d{
   NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:d];
   NSString *value = [newDict valueForKey:@"idexpert"];
   [newDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:[value longValue]] forKey:@"idexpert"];
   [super setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:newDict];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to manage JSON attributes while saving in core data is to write a generic function that can override setValuesForKeysWithDictionary as per below:

```
@implementation NSManagedObject (safeSetValuesKeysWithDictionary)

- (void)safeSetValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)keyedValues dateFormatter:(NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = [[self entity] attributesByName];
    for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
        id value = [keyedValues objectForKey:attribute];
        if (value == nil) {
            continue;
        }
        NSAttributeType attributeType = [[attributes objectForKey:attribute] attributeType];
        if ((attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
            value = [value stringValue];
        } else if (((attributeType == NSInteger16AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger32AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger64AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType)) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value integerValue]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSFloatAttributeType) &&  ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSDateAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) && (dateFormatter != nil)) {
            value = [dateFormatter dateFromString:value];
        }
        [self setValue:value forKey:attribute];
    }
}
@end
```

For more details refer this link here: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/